# Is there something similar to Maven Cargo but for AppAssembler?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-cargo, appassembler

I want to deploy a generated [Maven AppAssembler](http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/) `assembler/` directory to somewhere in a file system, SSH, or whatnot.  Can [Cargo](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin) do that for me, or is there an equivalent deployment tool that will let me glob a bunch of files (in this case the `target/appassembler/` directory) and deploy them to a destination?

I have a couple command-line applications that run as scheduled tasks (via cron or Windows Scheduler), and I want to deploy them out to these remote locations (in one case via SSH, and another a network share `\\servername\C$\whatever\`).  I don't know how I can accomplish that, since all of the deployment plugins I have been looking at cater to web applications and app containers or Remote repos like Nexus.

Answer (score 1):

Try [maven copy plugin](http://evgeny-goldin.com/wiki/Copy-maven-plugin) - it has excellent [networking support](http://evgeny-goldin.com/wiki/Copy-maven-plugin#Networking_Support) (scp,FTP,HTTP).
You might also find useful [maven sshexec plugin](http://evgeny-goldin.com/wiki/Sshexec-maven-plugin).

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is quite old, but since someone else might also be interested in this:

I don't have a complete/concrete example for this, since I never tried it, but maybe the [maven assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) could be used for this, with the dir assembly format?